# Why Environment.Exit cause LINQPad to terminate

Tags: c#, linqpad

I am debugging a program containing `Environment.Exit(0);` in `LINQPad`.

When this line `Environment.Exit(0);` hits, `LINQPad` exits.

1. Why does it happen? (In `Visual Studio`, obviously just the process terminates).
2. Is there a way to prevent this behavior without changing the original source ?

Simple example:

```
void Main()
{
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Because that is what it does - exit the process. Visual Studio (I assume you mean in the immediate window) uses the "_myapp_.vshost.exe" process to execute your commands in, so it exits this, not VS itself.

Comment: So the LINQPad assembly runs on the same process with the assembly I am debugging.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This happens because LINQPad executes queries in the same process as itself, isolating queries via application domain rather than process.

This has changed [in the latest beta](http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx): LINQPad now runs each query in its own process. This is in preparation for the upcoming integrated debugger (it's impossible debug your own process). A pleasant side-effect is that calling Environment.Exit (or throwing a StackOverflowException) no longer crashes the host process.

Comment: I'm using often Linqpad and I'm glad to read that ! Thank you very much for it, keep up the good work !

Comment: If I could only accept both of the great answers... thanks for a great book and software.

Answer (score 4):

LINQPad hosts executed code in an asynchronous thread (to not lock the UI) of its own process, so when you run instructions such as Environment.Exit, hosting process (hence Linqpad itself) is affected too.

You can easily check this by running a long program which makes some calculations : there is no new process in task manager, and linqpad process CPU usage is raising according to computations.

You can tweak a few things in Advanced Options related to application domain for example, but AFAIK there is no way to avoid this behavior since Linqpad entirely relies on this way to execute code.

Comment: +1, thanks for the explanation, that's exactly what I thought, note that this will change in one of the upcoming versions.